Streaming mp3 using node http to Icecast server gives no output
I'm trying to stream a custom mp3 datastream to Icecast2. Icecast recognises there's a mountpoint, however the streamed data won't play and I have no idea why.
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import { request } from 'node:http';

const req = request(
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/radio',
    method: 'PUT',
    auth: 'source:password',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
      Expect: '100-continue',
      'Ice-Public': 0,
      'Ice-Name': 'Testing Stream!',
      'Ice-Description': 'Testing Stream!',
      'Ice-Genre': 'Various',
      'Icy-MetaData': 1
      //'Icy-MetaInt': metaInt
    }
  },
  (res) => {
    console.log('Server responded with status code:', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log('Response chunk:', chunk.toString());
    });
  }
);

req.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error streaming to Icecast server:', err);
});

req.on('close', () => {
  console.error('Icecast server closed connection');
  process.exit(1);
});

req.on('continue', () => {
  console.log('Continue event received');
  ffmpeg({ source: 'test.mp3' })
    .native()
    .outputOption(['-map 0:a'])
    .audioBitrate(320)
    .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
    .audioFrequency(44100)
    .audioChannels(2)
    .format('mp3')
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
      console.log('Is open:' + req.socket.writable + ' - ' + progress.timemark);
    })
    .on('start', function (commandLine) {
      console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('Processing finished !');
      req.end();
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('FFmpeg error:', err);
    })
    .pipe(req);
});

Note that when I try to do this with ffmpeg using the icecast protocol, it works without issues: ffmpeg -re -i test.mp3 -b:a 320k -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 2 -map 0:a -f mp3 icecast://source:password@localhost:8000/radio. It looks like something is not right with request.

Are you actually getting the continue event?  I'm not sure that Icecast actually sends the HTTP/1.1 100 Continue.  And then, is your test file long enough?  Assuming all that is good, can you use a packet capture via Wireshark or similar to see what's going on with that source connection?  And then, assuming data is flowing through on the source end, do a packet capture to check between Icecast and the player.  That will help narrow down where the problem is.

@Brad the problem lies somewhere within http.request - I just wrote a lower level  Socket implementation and now it works. (Yes, i got the continue event, yes the file was 3 minutes)

Hmmmm, what version of Node?  Since it is HTTP/1.1 compatible, have you considered using the Fetch API instead?  You should be able to use a WHAT-WG stream as the request body.  You could use a passthrough/identity stream for the request body and then pipe FFmpeg to it, if that makes the API work easier.  You'll have to convert though from the Node.js stream to the WHAT-WG stream.  There's an API for that in node:streams... I don't remember what it is off the top of my head.  I can check the docs later tonight if you can't find it.

I implemented a lower-lever version, using createConnection instead of going through the request. This works.
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import { Writer } from 'icy';
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'node:fs';
import { request } from 'node:http';
import { createConnection } from 'node:net';

const METAINT = 8192;

const socket = createConnection(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  let auth = Buffer.from('source:password').toString('base64');
  let headers = `PUT /radio HTTP/1.1\r\n`;
  headers += `Host: 127.0.0.1:8000\r\n`;
  headers += `Authorization: Basic ${auth}\r\n`;
  headers += `User-Agent: Streamline/0.1\r\n`;
  headers += `Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n`;
  headers += `Expect: 100-continue\r\n`;
  headers += `Ice-Public: 0\r\n`;
  headers += `Ice-Name: Testing Stream\r\n`;
  headers += `Ice-Description: Testing Stream\r\n`;
  headers += `Ice-Genre: Various\r\n`;
  headers += `Icy-MetaInt: ${METAINT}\r\n`;
  headers += `\r\n`;

  socket.write(headers);

  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.toString().includes('HTTP/1.1 100 Continue')) {
      console.log('Continue event received');

      const icyWriter = Writer(METAINT, {});

      ffmpeg(createReadStream('test.mp3'))
        .native()
        .outputOptions(['-map 0:a'])
        .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
        .audioBitrate(320)
        .audioFrequency(44100)
        .audioChannels(2)
        .format('mp3')
        .on('progress', (progress) => {
          console.log('Is open:' + socket.writable + ' - ' + progress.timemark);
        })
        .on('start', (commandLine) => {
          console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Processing finished!');
          socket.end();
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
          console.error('FFmpeg error:', err);
        })
        .pipe(icyWriter);

      icyWriter.on('data', (chunk) => {
        socket.write(chunk);
      });

      setInterval(() => {
        icyWriter.queue('Alice DJ - Better Off Alone');
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
});

